# Count # lines in perl using wc

Tags: perl, split, wc

This seems really simple but neither a google search nor a stackoverflow search turn anything up. Is there a reason people don't do it this way? Sorry if I'm missing something.

I tried

```
$B = `wc -l $fileB`;
print "$B\n";
@B_array = split /\s+/, $B; #try to split on whitespace
foreach my $item (@B_array) {
        print "$item\n";
}
```

but that doesn't split the output of `wc -l` for some reason.

Comment: What's your output look like?  You can just use `split(' ', $B)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code works on my computer, perhaps this is one of the reasons people avoid using external tools. You can do this with native Perl of course:

```
my $lc = 0;
open my $file, "<", "input" or die($!);
$lc++ while <$file>;
close $file;
print $lc, "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

This avoids the split problem, but using cat like this can be considered wasteful of resources.

```
$B = `cat $fileB | wc -l`;
```

`cat filename | wc -l` just produces a number of lines -- `wc` cannot get a file name as it is reading from a pipe into stdin.

Also `@array=split ' ', $B`  will work for you.

Comment: How does using cat avoid the split problem?

Comment: @squiguy, there is no filename in the wc output is why :)

Comment: @perreal That's true, just prints a number eh?

Comment: It produces nnnnnn as output instead of nnnnnnn filename